How to print examples when asked for --help in F# argu
Using this SO answer I can print info for all CLI options.
How can I add an Examples section after --help is printed?
Extending Argu's tutorial I would like to print the below on --help:
USAGE: gadget.exe [--help] [--working-directory <path>] [--listener <host> <port>] [--data <base64>]
                  [--port <tcp port>] [--log-level <level>] [--detach]

OPTIONS:

    --working-directory <path>
                          specify a working directory.
    --listener <host> <port>
                          specify a listener (hostname : port).
    --data <base64>       binary data in base64 encoding.
    --port <tcp port>     specify a primary port.
    --log-level <level>   set the log level.
    --detach              detach daemon from console.
    --help                display this list of options.
    
EXAMPLES:

custom text here ...



Had typed stuff about logging an issue etc, I see you have: https://github.com/fsprojects/Argu/issues/251 - will reply there

Argu doesn't support that yet git-hub issue. I ended up doing this:
let examples = """
EXAMPLE 1
    lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
"""

type CustomErrorHandler() =
    interface IExiter with
        member __.Name = "Exiter"
        member __.Exit (msg, code) =
            if code = ErrorCode.HelpText then
                printfn "%s" msg
                printfn "%s" examples
                exit 0
            else
              (ProcessExiter() :> IExiter).Exit(msg, code)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let parser = ArgumentParser.Create<CliArguments>(programName = "myTool", errorHandler = CustomErrorHandler())
  let results = parser.Parse argv
  ...

